# async function is preventing return false from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

I have written a small plugin to create a wizard. Each wizard step is a form and on click of "next" button I want to submit the form. I use AJAX for submitting the form and I want to wait for AJAX to complete before going to next step (if AJAX is successful) or stay on the same step (if AJAX fails). So I use `async` and `await` to achieve this and this works fine.

The issue arises because I want to validate the form before submitting: if validation fails then I `return false` and prevent ajax submission. Without `async` and `await` I have the normal behaviour and `return false` makes the wizard stay on the same page. With `async` and `await` it will not.

My code is the following:

```
            beforeNextStep: async function (currentStep) {
                if($('#smartcheckin' + currentStep).valid()){ //form compilato correttamente
                    if ($('#documento_caricato' + currentStep).val() == '') { //documento non caricato
                        swal.fire('SmartCheckin', 'Devi caricare un documento per proseguire', 'warning');
                        $('#smartcheckin' + currentStep).submit(function () {
                            return false; //non sottometto il form
                        });
                        return false; //non avanzo allo step dopo
                    }else{
                        $('#smartcheckin' + currentStep).submit(function () {
                            return false; //non sottometto il form
                        });
                        data=$('#smartcheckin'+ currentStep).serialize();
                        //AJAX PER INVIARE IL FORM
                        return await $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType:'JSON',
                            url: 'endpoints/checkin.php',
                            data: data,
                        })
                        .done(function(data){
                            if(data.status==200){
                                //le cose sono andate bene
                                Toast.fire({icon: 'success',title: 'Checkin effettuato correttamente'});
                                if(currentStep<allSteps){
                                    return true;
                                }else{
                                    location.href="thankyou.html?token="+token;
                                }
                            }else{
                                $.ajax({
                                    "url": "/mantisbt/api/rest/issues",
                                    "method": "POST",
                                    "timeout": 0,
                                    "headers": {
                                        "Authorization": "3O4DtX_cwU9d57FRGdVhi6qCagUNFU1E",
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                                    },
                                    "data": JSON.stringify({
                                        "summary": data.message.summary,
                                        "description": data.message.description,
                                        "additional_information": data.message.additional_information,
                                        "project": { "id": 1, "name": "smartreservation"},
                                        "category": {"id": 5, "name": "bugtracker"},
                                        "handler": {"name": "lelio"},
                                        "view_state": {"id": 10,"name": "public"},
                                        "priority": {"name": "normal"},
                                        "severity": {"name": "crash"},
                                        "reproducibility": {"name": "sometimes"},
                                        "sticky": false,
                                        /* "custom_fields": [],
                                        "tags": [] */
                                    })
                                }).done(function(data){
                                    Toast.fire({
                                        icon: 'error',
                                        title: 'Problemi a effettuare il checkin. Una segnalazione è stata aperta al nostro reparto tecnico'
                                    });
                                });
                                return false; //non avanzo allo step dopo
                            }       
                        });
                    }
                }else{
                    console.log('false returned');
                    return false; //form non valido non vado oltre
                }
            },
```

Look just at the first if: when the validation returns false the wizard returns false. Without `async` and `await` I never see the message `false returned` from the console

How to fix this?
**EDIT**: note that the async await part per se works fine. So if the form validation is fine await gives me the expected behavior

The plugin code for this is just:

```
        beforeNextStep: function (t) {
            return !0
        },
```

so that i can fully customize it on the client side each time I run it. Should I make also this an async function?

Edit 2: the plugin initiation where I define this function:

```
    $("#mydiv").accWizard({
            mode: displayMode,
            //mode: 'wizard',
            //autoButtons: true,
            start: stepToDisplay, //lo step da cui partire
            autoButtonsNextClass: 'btn btn-primary float-right',
            autoButtonsPrevClass: 'btn btn-light',
            stepNumberClass: 'badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-1',
            beforeNextStep: async function (currentStep) {
                if($('#smartcheckin' + currentStep).valid()){
                    ... rest of my code here
```

Comment: I think you see no "false returned" because you log it after the return so it's never executed. I see no issue with the code.

Comment: How do you handle beforeNextStep return value?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus if it is true then the next step is shown, if false it is not. This works fine if you just avoid using async

Comment: @chack1172 that's right, was a typo in the question

Comment: Whatever calls `beforeNextStep` needs to be able to handle promises,  as it's never going to return false, it's going to return a Promise that might be false.

Comment: Can you add the client code where you use this method ?

Comment: What @Keith said is true, async function will alway return Promise which you have to handle. The issue here is not with this piece of code, rather in code that handler return value from this method.

Comment: @Dilshan this is the client code

Comment: @Keith can you elaborate on this? You spotted the light but I then need an hint on what to do next.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, replace return false with throwing an error and simply handle this like

```
try {
  await beforeNextStep()
} catch {
  // Fire error toast
}

// continue execution as if everything is okay
```

or if you want to have the same false logic then do it like this

```
const result = await beforeNextStep()

if (!result) { // check if false is returned
  // Fire error toast
  return // exit the function to stop further code execution
}

// continue execution as if everything is okay
```

Comment: thanks for the hint but please see the edit in my question, how can I implement it in plugin initiation?